# Laravel manage global settings

Tags: php, laravel

I need to manage some settings in globally throughout entire laravel lifecycle.

Something related to changing language of website.

But my question is I want to apply current settings to filter out data.

For example I have customer and product tables each has year column. Now if I set particular year as global settings. All the data within application must filter out based on that year.

Any efficient way to manage it.

Sorry I'm new to this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you using View Composers

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    // Your filter out data here
    // $filtredData = ....
    return $view->with('data', 'filtredData');
});
```

> The `*` character  allow you to attach a composer to all views

See [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers)